# Thymeleaf Multiple Input Tags with same name

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I came from a PHP background.

Adding multiple input tags with the same name is as simple as:

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]"/>
<input type="text" name="phone[]"/>
```

Then i'll receive them in the controller as an array of two phone numbers.

How can i implement the same with thymeleaf?
Keep in mind that the phone number isn't fixed to two and can be dynamically generated via a js function

Answer (score 1):

You can take input for multiple value in array list way

```
<form th:object="${details}">
    <input type="text" name="*{phone[0]}"/>
    <input type="text" name="*{phone[1]}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What if the inputs are generated dynamically via javascript?

Comment: Generate index also

Comment: Yes i can add index ONLY if i know the count of names from server before loading thymeleaf. What if am adding the fields dynamically via JS, how do i do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: `What if am adding the fields dynamically via JS` when generate input tag how you generate? Make a counter just increase by 1 every time add one `0....`